# Get information from two vertices in Azure CosmosDB Graph (GREMLIN API)

Tags: azure, graph, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

[image]

I would like to create a query which gets information from two vertices. I have **Vertex A** and **Vertex B** and I need from **Vertex A** the value of property **label** and of properties array the value **schema**. From **Vertex B** I only would like to get the value of property **name**. I tried multiple queries to get the result like:

```
[
  {
     "label" : "anySubTypeName",
     "schema": ".....",
     "name"  : "anyTypeName"
   },
   ...
]
```

I was able to get properties **name** of each vertex but not **schema** with following query:

```
g.V().hasLabel("subtype").as("subtype")
     .outE("typeof").inV().as("type")
     .select("subtype", "type").by("id")
____________________

Result:

[
  {
    "subtype": "anySubTypeName",
    "type"   :  "anyTypeName"
  }
]
```

Can anyone help me that I also can get **schema** as part of the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to get the expected result with the following query:

```
g.V().haslabel("subtype").as("subtype")
     .outE("typeof").inV().as("type")
     .select("subtype", "type").by("id")
```